# "社長に議長に田中氏を任命された” is ambiguous?

Tags: passive-voice, ambiguity

> 社長に議長に田中氏が任命された。

i think the possible meanings are:

> 1. Mr. Tanaka was appointed by the chairman to be the president.
> 2. Mr. Tanaka was appointed by the president to be the chairman.

Is that all correct?

Using the idea in this thread [The grammar of “虎から食べられた” and “虎に食べられた”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/the-grammar-of-%E8%99%8E%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F-and-%E8%99%8E%E3%81%AB%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F) is maybe this a possible remedy:

> 社長**から**議長に田中氏を任命された。

making it unambiguous and meaning

> Mr. Tanaka was appointed to be the chairman by the president.

Does changing "**に**" to "**から**" both sound natural and remove ambiguity?

Comment: 英文では「Mr. Tanaka was appointed～」と、「Mr. Tanaka」が主語だから、日本語も「田中氏**は/が** ～～任命された。」とした方が自然なのでは？

Comment: Using によって is another way to clarify passive sentences that have both a "by ~" and an indirect object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. 社長から議長に田中氏を任命された is a solution to get rid of ambiguity.

Comment: @Will It seems a little rude to say it's not worthy of *any* upvotes... (it's like saying "this is so bad I'd downvote it multiple times if I could", no?). I'd rather have native speakers feel comfortable responding on the site without feeling they need to write a detailed explanation each time.

Comment: @Will  "fix the erroneous を particle!" >> It's not necessarily "erroneous"... it'd be 「～を～される」in the indirect passive voice and 「～が～される」 in the direct passive voice...

Comment: If OP didn't understand the reason, I'd add some explanation. But one who offered the sentence is him.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this sentence is ambiguous as Japanese grammar.

As my point of view, I modified it like below.

社長   --> subject
田中氏 --> a target person
議長   --> An assigned post

The president appointed 田中氏 to the chairman.「社長は議長に田中氏を任命した」

At first, I think this is not the passive sentence.
And usage of a preposition is importance.
「は」「に」「から」「を」... and so on.
Because it is possible that the meaning change dramatically.

Please refer a site below.
http://nihongoichiban.com/home/japanese-grammar-particles/

Hope it helps.